# How to change specialty within my field without full time experience and reasonable pay?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, united-kingdom

I have 18 years industry experience and a degree.

I'd really love to gain employment with a different specialty, although I am a little concerned as there never seems to be many positions available in my area and job security. I can't move due to family commitments. I'd previously given up on the idea, but was encouraged by a friend.

I've been developing working in my desired specialty in my spare time since 2010 and for a period of six months working for myself in 2010. I have two products that have reached market.

My current position of some years is in a dying specialty which is hurting my marketability. I do have some prospects with a far more popular language but I'm not sure I enjoy it.

I recently went for an interview and didn't get to job as I wanted more money than they were prepared to pay. They wanted to start me at an intern salary. They did ask me some questions regarding my desired specialty which I believe I answered 80% correctly. I have heard since that the company is known for not paying well.

I did ask for feedback and where I was lacking, but I didn't get a reply :(

My question, how can I change specialty without a pay cut?

Comment: So, how did it happen: You went for the interview not knowing how much they were offering, or they bait-and-switched on you? I've been knocked down 1K before (suspect by the recruiter), but nothing more than that.

Comment: @weston I gave salary expectations, when I applied

Comment: I do not think they should have interviewed you if they weren't willing to get even close to your expectations.

Comment: Don't get discouraged by being rejected from one job application - competition is tight.  You just have to keep trying.

Comment: Thanks Zibbobz :), it's a difficult situation, hard to leverage the skills I do have in the direction I want to go.

Comment: Editted to be less industry specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look for a job that has a mixture of iOS and another technology, that way you can keep your higher salary from your experience in said other technology while getting commercial experience in iOS.

If these are hard to come by, remember to keep iOS personal experience on your CV and talk about it in interviews. This could create this mixed tech position in companies that had previously not considered it.

My current position was advertised as a pure back-end developer but they were very excited to hear about my personal mobile experience and now I do a 70/30 back-end/mobile split which is something, but I at least have the commercial experience to go 100% mobile in another position if I wish. I too am older with 14 years experience and I took no pay hit.

In mean time update your online presence with things like a GitHub account, post some iOS app examples on it that employers can use to get a feel for your skill level.

Comment: Thank Weston unfortunately I'm not on a high salary, having said that it's very difficult to find a role which will allow for such a mix even approaching the salary I'm on. I like the GitHub idea, I had thought about posting some utility functions as a starter but I guess from a prospective employers point of view that wouldn't be too impressive.

Comment: I know they my goal here is to get a iOS position, by doing my iOS projects, however I do like to make a little money from them, posting a whole app will be difficult. I guess I'll have to think of some middle ground, maybe some test apps for functionality I employ in my apps.

Comment: "unfortunately I'm not on a high salary" higher is what I meant, higher than the £20K entry level iOs job

Comment: Yes I meant post experimental apps, demos, that kind of thing. Fork and modify other peoples examples too. Maybe even make suggestions via pull-requests back to libraries and examples. Anything that shows activity will be good for you.

Answer (score 2):

> My question, how can I gain an iOS developer full time position
>   without a pay cut?

You have 18 years of work experience, and presumably a salary that reflects this experience.

But you have little experience in iOS, and may not be able to command the salary you are currently earning.

Your best bet might be to find a position where you can leverage your 18 years of experience while making the transition to iOS. Look for something in your experience domain - perhaps a company embarking on iOS for the first time.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't command a high salary, I spend ten years working for myself and didn't update my skills. In my present position new languages were promised but I'm stuck with good legacy skills. You have given me an idea though, maybe I should primary look at a mobile developer role or any iOS roles which seem suitable.

Comment: This is good advice but unfortunately if OP's experience is in something like COBOL that opportunity may never arise...